# How to save file safely when using MediaStore content provider and EXTRA_OUTPUT of camera intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera-intent, android-contentresolver

I want to take picture using the `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent, and then save it to a specific path with `contentresolver.insert()` and passed the uri with `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Here is how I do it(with permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` granted):

```
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
val imageData = ContentValues()
val imageTableUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
imageData.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "${filename}.jpg")
imageData.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
imageData.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/MyPath")
val imageUri = contentResolver.insert(imageTableUri, imageData)
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
intent.also { takePictureIntent ->
    takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager).also {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, takePictureRequestCode)
    }
}
```

This code will work. But if I:

1. Cancel the camera intent by the Back button, or
2. Switch to other apps while staying in the camera invoked by my activity

the Photo app will show a incomplete photo, whose information cannot be shown:
[incomplete photo in Photo app(indicated by the red square)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x65z0.jpg)

Furthermore, the same `DISPLAY_NAME` will cause `contentResolver.insert()` to return `null` even if I have manually deleted that incomplete photo(with Photo app or File Manager), and I also cannot find the file by `contentResolver.query()` with the clause selecting that file name.

For the first case, I may invoke `contentResolver.delete()` in `onActivityResult()` method of my activity since the uri may be kept. But is there a way to handle the second case(which may sometimes cause the application end directly)? Or did I misuse one of contentResolver or the camera intent?

Comment: An incomplete photo is a jpg file with filesize 0?

Comment: In the attached image, if I click into the photo, the information button doesn't respond, so I'm not sure how to check that.

Comment: WIth a filemanager go to the directory and the file.

Comment: If you want to avoid all this troubel you better let the camera app save the picture to a private directory of your app using a file provider. After that in onActivity result add the picture to the mediastore and the lete the private file.

Comment: Sorry I'm not able make the file visible in the file manager currently(only visible in Photo app). But I will use the method you provide. However, how can I delete this kind of incomplete file if it is created under my own private directory(If I still cannot query the file as I did with MediaStore, but I will first check if that really happens though)?

Comment: Maybe you cant delete it as it is still indexed by the media store. A rescan or reboot migth help.